# wx python cursor not released after mouse up event

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using a slider control to set a dimension in my application. Unfortunately the cursor seems to be locked to the slider control after the EVT_LEFT_UP event and I need to click somewhere else on the application to release it. I am probably missing something simple, but what is it?

```
    import wx


    class Example(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Slider control')
            self.Centre()
            self.sldr_size = wx.Slider(self, 100, 0, 1, 100, size=(250, -1), style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL )
            self.sldr_size.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.sldr_size_button_up)
            sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
            sizer.Add(self.sldr_size, pos=(0, 0))
            self.SetSizer(sizer)
            self.sldr_size.SetValue(33)
            self.Show()

        def sldr_size_button_up(self, event):
            del event
            self.item_size = 1.3 - float(self.sldr_size.GetValue())/100
            print self.item_size

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        simple_screen_app = wx.App()
        main_frame = Example()
        main_frame.Show(True)
        simple_screen_app.MainLoop()
```

Edit: simplify code

Comment: what is your OS/toolkit? wxpython/python version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native slider widget most likely has a build-in event handler for EVT_LEFT_UP which releases the mouse capture.  Since you have intercepted  the EVT_LEFT_UP event then you are preventing that built-in handler from being called.  You can tell the event processing system to continue looking for matching handlers, as it would have if yours was not there, by calling `event.Skip()` in your handler.

Comment: Perfect Robin. Thank you